# Instantiating arbitrary classes thru Spring

Tags: java, spring, inversion-of-control

I'm writing a service registry class. This service registry will scan packages for annotated classes and then populate some internal map. What I need then, is to be able to query for services (by String name) using some method (let's say `Object get(String name)`). This method will then search internal map for a service with such name and returns instance.

What I'm doing right now, is having this ServiceRegistryBean implement `ApplicationContextAware` and `BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor` and a list of Strings (package names) given on construct.

Then, as soon as the bean is constructed, registry post processor kicks in (see note) and the registry class adds the service classes as new beans (singleton, lazy loaded) to the spring bean registry. Then, getting the service instance is as simple as requesting a bean from context, returning singleton instance.

My question is: is there a better way in Spring to do this? I've looked into bean factories, but it does not seem to me the same. Support for auto-wiring and DI in service instances is essential, that's why I want Spring to instantiate it. Also, I like the idea of Spring taking care of singletons.

Note: I've found out, that when I inline the bean creation in `<constructor-arg>` (that is, bean is not named and is just an instance passed as constructor argument of other bean - in my case, I'm passing registry as a parameter to other constructor), `BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor` interface methods (namely `public void postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(BeanDefinitionRegistry registry)`) is not called at all! I'm quite sure, it is some behavior of Spring I don't know about, but I was not able to find proper documentation for the post-processor.

Thank you for any hints or insights!

Answer (score 0):

Scanning for custom annotations it's already supported, you only need to add a `include-filter` to `<context:component-scan>` tag, ie

```
<context:component-scan base-package="org.example">
   <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="some.Annotation"/>
</context:component-scan>
```

see http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-scanning-filters

If you turn on `default-lazy-init` I suppose that the DI Container is ready to use as Service Locator Registry.

About the note, only root bean definitions are taken into account when looking for `BeanFactoryPostProcessors`, inner beans are ignored.

Usually, scanning and registering beans is done by `BeanDefinitionParsers` instead because you known when the beans are registered and beans are visible for tools, like STS Spring Bean Explorer, but using a `BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor` is correct. The interface ensures that beans are defined before other `BeanFactoryPostProcessors` run.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but I'm afraid, I have reasons to have actual registry class and not use Spring discovery services (one of them is, that the library should support non-Spring deployment and also, that the annotation itself has some other metadata associated, that needs to be taken into account)